# Angular Periodic request

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

i am working with Angular5, and right now I make requests each 5 sec to check the condition of the task.
But I want to make the condition more flexible check "if the request has status code 202 make requests if 200 stop sends requests". or mb someone has better practice to do that.

```
#some.component.ts
  RunAsyncUpdates() {
   this._asyncService.getAsyncDataSource(this.model.id)
   .pipe(
    map(
    (resp: any) => {
      # i realy have no idea how to do this, but i am sure code must be here
      return resp.body;
    }),
    repeatWhen(() => Observable.interval(5000)),
    retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(1000).take(3)),
    takeWhile(() => this._alive)
  )
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      if (!data) { return; }
      console.log(data);
      this._asyncService.data_stream$.next(data);
    }
  );



#some.service.ts
getAsyncDataSource(item): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
const uri = `${this.base_service.getBaseUrl()}/async/${item}/`;
return this.httpClient.get<any>(uri, {observe: 'response'});
```

**EDIT:** this works very well

```
this.route.parent.params.pipe(
  switchMap((params: Params) => this._asyncService.loadAsyncData(params['id'])
// get parametr from route
    .pipe(
      map((resp: any) => {
          if (resp.status !== 202) {
            throw resp; // This error will be picked up by retryWhen
          }
          return resp.body;
        }),
      repeatWhen(() => Observable.interval(5000)),
      retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(1000).take(3)),
      takeWhile(() => this._alive),
    )),
  takeWhile(() => this._alive),
).subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      if (!data) {return; }
      this._asyncService.data_stream$.next(data);
    }
  );
```

Comment: use `setInterval`

Comment: mb you can share code how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're right that the code should be in `.map()`. According to the [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html), that is where you put your custom condition that decides whether to throw an error for a given response.

```
RunAsyncUpdates() {
   this._asyncService.getAsyncDataSource(this.model.id)
   .pipe(
    map(
    (resp: any) => {
      if (resp.status === 202) {
        throw resp // This error will be picked up by retryWhen
      }
      return resp.body;
    }),
    repeatWhen(() => Observable.interval(5000)),
    retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(1000).take(3)),
    takeWhile(() => this._alive)
  )
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      if (!data) { return; }
      console.log(data);
      this._asyncService.data_stream$.next(data);
    }
  );
```